# TypeError: pad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, huggingface-transformers

The following is the problem I encountered

```
The `max_size` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in v4.26. Please specify in `size['longest_edge'] instead`.
Some weights of the model checkpoint at facebook/detr-resnet-50 were not used when initializing DetrForObjectDetection: ['model.backbone.conv_encoder.model.layer3.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked', 'model.backbone.conv_encoder.model.layer2.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked', 'model.backbone.conv_encoder.model.layer1.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked', 'model.backbone.conv_encoder.model.layer4.0.downsample.1.num_batches_tracked']
- This IS expected if you are initializing DetrForObjectDetection from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing DetrForObjectDetection from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
  0%|                                                                                        | 0/18690 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\wwh\TransformerTest\ObjectDetect.py", line 94, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1553, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1813, in _inner_training_loop
    for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\accelerate\data_loader.py", line 384, in __iter__
    current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 681, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 721, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_utils.py", line 707, in __call__
    return self.data_collator(features)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 249, in __call__
    batch = self.tokenizer.pad(
TypeError: pad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'
  0%|          | 0/18690 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Hi,friends.I encounter a question when I used huggging face transformers to train a object detect model.I found a lot of way to solve this problem such as chatgpt rectify,changing version of library,and reinstall it.So I look forward you can assistant me to do this problem.thanks you very much.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from transformers import DetrImageProcessor, DetrForObjectDetection
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
from PIL import Image
import os

# 检查是否有可用的 GPU
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    print("GPU 可用，将在 GPU 上运行")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("GPU 不可用，将在 CPU 上运行")

# 预训练 DETR 模型和图像处理器
model_name = "facebook/detr-resnet-50"
processor = DetrImageProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name, local_files_only=True)
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(model_name, local_files_only=True)
model.to(device)

# 数据集的根目录
data_dir = "./VOC"

# 训练、测试和验证集文件路径
train_file = "./VOC/train.txt"
test_file = "./VOC/test.txt"
val_file = "./VOC/val.txt"

# 自定义数据加载器
class CustomCOCODataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, annotation_file, processor):
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.processor = processor
        self.data = []
        with open(annotation_file, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                image_path = line  # 图像路径
                self.data.append((image_path))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = self.data[idx]
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.data_dir, image_path)).convert("RGB")
        inputs = self.processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")

        # 从标签文件中读取标签信息
        label_path = os.path.join(self.data_dir, "labels", os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0] + ".txt")
        with open(label_path, 'r') as label_file:
            labels = [float(label) for label in label_file.read().strip().split()]  # 修改这里为浮点数

        target = {
            "labels": torch.tensor(labels),
        }
        return inputs, target

# 创建自定义数据集
train_dataset = CustomCOCODataset(data_dir, train_file, processor)
test_dataset = CustomCOCODataset(data_dir, test_file, processor)
val_dataset = CustomCOCODataset(data_dir, val_file, processor)

# 数据加载器
train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, collate_fn=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=processor))
test_data_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=2, collate_fn=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=processor))
val_data_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=2, collate_fn=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=processor))

# 训练参数
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./output",  # 训练结果的保存路径
    num_train_epochs=10,  # 训练的轮数
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,  # 每个 GPU 的训练批次大小
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,  # 每个 GPU 的评估批次大小
    save_steps=100,  # 保存模型的步数
    evaluation_strategy="steps",  # 评估策略
    save_total_limit=1,  # 保存的最大模型数量
    logging_dir="./logs",  # 添加日志记录目录
)

# 创建 Trainer 对象
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=processor),
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
)

# 开始微调
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()

# 您现在可以使用微调后的模型进行推断和评估
```

Comment: what is the version of your `transformers`? You can find it from the terminal via `pip show transformers`